# Electron-Builder autoUpdater not detecting new updates?

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

**Summary**

I have an electron/electron-builder + react app. I'm trying to implement autoUpdater. I can publish just fine, but opening up the production app doesn't seem to do anything. I have a private repo, GH environment variables set, and my GH token in the code.

I'm on this config:

```
"electron": "^7.1.9",
"electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
"electron-updater": "^4.2.0",
```

Here's the steps i take to test:

1. push new version to github
2. run the build/publish script.
3. publish release on github
4. download the exe and run the app.
5. edit package.json with new version
6. push to github
7. run the build/publish script.
8. publish release on github

I then would open the app again, but nothing happens. I let it sit for a while to see if maybe its just downloading in the background, but each time nothing happens. No update ever downloads or even installs. I know this because on one of my pages, I import the package.json and have a text field that shows the version from that file. The version never changes. Heres the code I use from the auto-updater docs:

**Main.js**:

```
app.on('ready', function(){
  createWindow()
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
})
```

I've tried the manual implementation, but still, nothing happens when I publish new builds.

Here is my build script in package.json:

```
"build": {
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "github",
        "owner": "githubname",
        "repo": "reponame",
        "private": true,
        "token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      }
    ],
    "appId": "nonExistentID",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    },
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "node_modules/regedit/vbs",
        "to": "regedit/vbs",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Errors:**

I have found one error when attempting manual updates with `autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();` I added an autoUpdater.on('error') and was hit with the following error: `Error: Redirect was cancelled`

This error was fixed by updating electron version from 7.1.2 to 7.1.9. Now I'm met with the following error:

`404 Not Found` followed by a link that looks sorta like this: `api.github/something/user/releases/latest/2304235`

I then tried testing out that link in the browser, and found almost all links i tried were either unauthorized or 404'd. GitHub says in dev docs that they will often push 404 to not expose extra info when its actually an unauthorized call.

Comment: This is a known bug in electron since version `7.1.3` See: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/4505 try updating to: electron version `7.1.8`

Comment: Has anyone actually found a solution to this?

Comment: switching the repo to public fixed all my errors. private was just too buggy.